# how to set border radius for IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make rounded border in IE8 with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130460/how-to-make-rounded-border-in-ie8-with-css)

Is there any css code for border-radius for images in IE. I am getting the radius in all other browsers but not in IE. any one please help me

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130460/how-to-make-rounded-border-in-ie8-with-css

Comment: IE will always be one or two versions behind every other browser.

Answer (score 0):

border-radius property comes only in CSS3 and IE8 has not native support for CSS3. CSS3 support is only available from IE9. Try using modernizr which will give some sort of CSS3 support for older browsers

http://www.modernizr.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modernizr

Comment: Modernizr doesn't give you any features, it only detects if a browser supports them or not.