# How can I make css support old versions of browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, browser-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make rounded border in IE8 with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130460/how-to-make-rounded-border-in-ie8-with-css)

I set this code for Border. I need to set rounded corners for this border.

This code works **with E9**, I need it to **work in old browser like IE6, IE7, IE8**

My code in **CSS**

```
 border-radius: 11px 11px;
 border:1px solid #373737;
 -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
 -moz-border-radius: 11px;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest CSS3 PIE - http://css3pie.com/

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support of `border-radius` in older browsers, you got to use scripts such as **[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)** to get it working in them.

Be aware that in your CSS, you will have to use `behaviour` property which isn't valid and will cause your CSS not to validate against W3C Validator.