# How to use border-radious in ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, border, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make rounded border in IE8 with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130460/how-to-make-rounded-border-in-ie8-with-css)

I use css border-radius for design webpages. The site good run in firefox but don't run with ie8. Everyone can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for `border-radius` in IE8. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)'s information on `border-radius` support.

Your best bet is to use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to fill in the gaps if your rounded corners are really that important. That or some other kind of [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills). Otherwise just make sure what you have created [gracefully degrades](http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignglossary/g/graceful-degradation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426979/border-radius-for-ie8), but there's no way you can achieve round corners only with CSS in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

No border support for IE-8, you can achieve the same effect using a plugin

http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use this might be useful [ie-css3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)